# How can I store the values inputted by the user to the matrix (shiny)

Tags: r, matrix, shiny

Background:
Basically, I already have a matrix where user can input how many rows the matrix will have and what values are within the matrix. The code below already does that for me.

However, I do not know how and where I can store this matrix.

I wanted a way to store the user-inputted matrix as I'm going to pass it to my QSI program by directly calling the function in my QSI program within the server.

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  output$simplex_dataPoints <- renderUI({  
    #For QSI
    dpc = input$dataPointsCount
    validate(            
      need(isTruthy(dpc),label = "rows"),    
     
    )
    
    
    matrixInput("matrix1",  
                value = matrix(data= 0,  
                               nrow= dpc,   
                               ncol= 2,
                               dimnames = list(c(1:dpc),c("x","y"))
                ),  
                
                rows = list( 
                  n=dpc,              
                  names = TRUE,         
                  editableNames = FALSE
                ),   
                cols = list (
                  n= 2,                
                  names = TRUE,            
                  editableNames = FALSE     
                ),
                class = "numeric")        
    
  })
  
  
}
```

I haven't seen any answers here regarding my query so I'm not sure where to start.

Comment: If the processing is not in same app, you can save entered data on a shared drive or cloud drive. But it's unusual to separate entry and processing

Comment: Sorry I think you might've misunderstood what I meant. What I mean is I already created a program for QSI. I'm just going to use source() so that I can call the function in my QSI program.